# Disable form control of form array : Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a FormArray with a List of formGroups.

Now, I am trying to disable the control of each formGroup by looping FormArray.

```
this.otcDocumentTrackerForm.controls.forEach(s => {
  s.controls["isNotApproved"].disabled();
  s.controls["CREDIT_OR_OPS_REMARKS"].disabled();
});
```

However, this is not working for me.  Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable form controls by iterating through form array

```
diableInputs() {
    this.myForm.controls.forEach((group: FormGroup) => {
        let isNotApproved = group.get('isNotApproved') as FormControl;
        isNotApproved.disable()
        let credit = group.get('CREDIT_OR_OPS_REMARKS') as FormControl;
        credit.disable()
    })
}
```

Check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8mkuo) for complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Try `disabling` the `form control` when you are creating it.

For example :

`isNotApproved: new FormControl({ value: false, disabled: true }, Validators.required)`